# CSS: height: 90vh !important; on Table Not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, safari

I am having a lot of trouble getting the command height: 90vh !important; to work on the whole table. I have tried a few things but nothing seems to work. It works perfectly as desired in firefox, but for some reason it does not work at all in chrome or safari. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

The code can be inspected here

http://dev.eteacher.online/error12

Comment: And if you shuffle all your elements around so that the document becomes valid HTML, does it work then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly.

Comment: Well, your document starts with the <head>, then two <script>s, then <html> and then <body>. That is not how it should be! And I can't repeat it often enough: different browsers respond differently to errors! If your document is free of errors, then the chances of it looking the same in different browsers increase drastically.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it. And you should see that it has valid html now. Still does not work as it is supposed to.

Comment: The link in your question still points to the same invalid page.

Comment: the urls are all incorrect yes, mostly because this is just an example of the error. It does the same behaviour when the links are functional. I know the CSS code has a lot of funky messages. I got this from a creative commons. How might I deal with all this?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lister. So I decided to remove all the style on the page. Since it's all extra. And used for other pages. I simplified it and it seems to work very well. Thanks